# How to make an event toggle HTML class on one element while removing it from others?

Tags: javascript, html

So, I have a little project that showcases a set of images, small-size. And when you click on one of them, it expands. Basically, JavaScript adds an HTML class of "active" to an element, which transforms it.

```
const panels = document.querySelectorAll('.panel');

/*adding an event for every image panel that makes
panel active on click */
panels.forEach(panel => {
    panel.addEventListener('click', () => {
        removeActiveClasses()
        panel.classList.add('active')
    })
})

//a function that removes active class from a panel
function removeActiveClasses() {
    panels.forEach(panel => {
        panel.classList.remove('active')
    })
}
```

So, when you click on the element, it removes all the .active classes from every other one, and then adds it to a target element. It works perfectly, but I want to be able to delete a class from an element that is currently active, so when I click on an expanded picture, it collapses back. Changing panel.classList.add to panel.classList.toggle obviously doesn't work, because it first removes all active classes and then "toggles" it (or adds, because there is none). How can I delete a class from active element on click, while remaining the other functionality?

Comment: Before you remove the active class from all elements, check whether the current element has it set, or not. Then use that information after, to remove or set the class for the current element.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? How can I target an element and check if it has an active class?

Comment: How did you “target” the element to _add_ the active class to it? You used `panel` to access it inside the event handler callback. And `classList` has a method `contains`, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: `panels.forEach(panel => {
    if(panel.classList.contains('active')) {
        panel.addEventListener('click', () => {
            panel.classList.remove('active')
        })
    } else {
    panel.addEventListener('click', () => {
        panel.classList.add('active')
    })
}
})`
So I've made a conditional like this, but it doesn't seem to work properly.

Comment: What is that, who said you should make adding of the event handlers themselves dependent on any condition? Keep everything as it was, and just add the following. You store whether the element currently has that class, into a variable: `var isActive = panel.classList.contains('active');` – that will contain either `true` or `false` now. Then you remove the class from all elements, and afterwards you toggle it for the current element, using the negated value of this variable: `panel.classList.toggle('active', !isActive);`

Comment: Thanks! That works like charm. I'll edit the post

Comment: No, please don’t make the question itself, also contain the solution. You can write a self-answer, if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:** Thanks to **CBroe** I've managed to make it work. The code now looks like the following:

```
const panels = document.querySelectorAll('.panel');

/*adding an event for every image panel that makes
panel active on click */
panels.forEach(panel => {
    panel.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const isActive = panel.classList.contains('active')
        removeActiveClasses()
        panel.classList.toggle('active', !isActive)
    })

})

//a function that removes active class from a panel
function removeActiveClasses() {
    panels.forEach(panel => {
        panel.classList.remove('active')
    })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A much more efficient way would be to :

```
document.getElementsByClassName('panel').addEventListener('click', function() {
   for (let ele of panels) {
    ele.classList.remove('active')
   }
   let panel = this
   panel.classList.includes('active') ? panel.classList.remove('active') : panel.classList.add('active')
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I get an error "panels.addEventListener is not a function".

Comment: you can't apply events directly to the element collection, you need to iterate through it